# How can I get the addition object for integers?

Tags: python

Is there any way in Python to get the addition object (operator +) for integers in Python and store it somewhere?

Comment: Please note that the answer is different depending on whether you specifically want the addition operator *for integers* or the general operation.

Comment: To get the bound add method of an integer you should use parentheses to prevent the `.` being treated as a decimal point. eg `(1).__add__`. Another way would be to add a space between the `1` and the `.` eg `1 .__add__` but I think that it is too obscure.

Comment: @gnibbler Great comment. I expanded the accepted answer based on it in the interests of a complete answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> int_add = int.__add__
>>> int_add(1, 2)
3
```

You can also use [`operator.add`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.add) to obtain a generic function for adding in Python:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> add(1, 2)
3
>>> add('a', 'b')
'ab'
```

If you want to get the addition method of a specific integer, instead of the `int` type, see gnibbler's comment on the question:

> To get the bound add method of an integer you should use parentheses to prevent the . being treated as a decimal point. eg **`(1).__add__`**. Another way would be to add a space between the **`1`** and the **`.`** eg **`1 .__add__`** but I think that it is too obscure.

An example:

```
>>> one_add = 1 .__add__
>>> one_add(2)
3
```

Comment: This one is more correct.  In at least some Python versions, `int.__add__ is operator.add` is false.

Comment: When `operator.add` is called with an integer as the first argument, `int.__add__` will be used.  For `operator.add(a, b)`, `a.__add__(b)` will be called if it is implemented, if it is not `b.__radd__(a)` will be attempted.

Comment: Adding on to F.J.:  The implication is that `int.__add__` will fail when called with non integer arguments: `int.__add__(2, 3.0)` will return the string value `"NotImplemented"`.  So if you're certain the arguments will always be integers, go ahead and use `int.__add__`.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import operator
>>> help(operator.add)
Help on built-in function add in module operator:

add(...)
    add(a, b) -- Same as a + b.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int.__add__`:

```
>>> myOperator = int.__add__
>>> myOperator(23,42)
65
```